# Ejabberd: bad argument in call to fxml:element_to_binary

Tags: module, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, sendmessage

I'm not well experienced in erlang but need to resolve some task.

I have added some processing before sending xml to user in ejabberd_c2s.erl file. If I recognize my custom tag I need to add another one to the message

this is original

```
send_element(StateData, El) ->
     send_text(StateData, fxml:element_to_binary(El)).
```

my change simplified is something like this

```
send_element(StateData, El) ->
     NewEl = fxml:append_subtags(El, [create_tag()]);
     send_text(StateData, fxml:element_to_binary(NewEl))

create_tag(Body) ->
#xmlel{name = <<"myTag">>, attrs = [<<"attrib1">>,<<"value1">>], children = []}.
```

Whatever I do I get error "bad argument in call to fxml:element_to_binary(..."

I have printed out the El before and  after adding tag and everything looks OK  after adding new tag

Comment: The simplified code could be correct, except that `Body` is unbound in `send_element/2`, unused in `create_tag/1` and assuming that `El` is a valid xml element. May be the issue is in the removed code.

Comment: @Pascal I cut out the code, so normally Body is not unbound (I updated now). The change is made in ejabbed_c2s.erl file